# Firefox 46 can't see child div for css and jquery

Tags: firefox

Hi to everyone I have a strange problem with Firefox 46, before the update my website work good, now if I go over the slider on top page it doesn't show me the custom cursor and if I click on it doesn't work the jquery function too.
On chrome, safari and also on the old version of FF it work; it's seems it can't see the div #banner because it's a child of others div containers, but why on the old version it work?
I'm confused
[here's the test page](http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/etoile/ristorante.html)

HTML code

```
<div class="parallax">
<header>
    <div id="cont_logo">
        <a class="logo" href="" rel="home"></a>
        <span>L'étoile</span>
        <span id="logo_text">Ristorante - Pizzeria - Steak House</span>
        <span>Courmayeur</span>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu_lang">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="" title="ita" >It</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="fra" >Fr</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="eng" >En</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="main_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" rel="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="ristorante.html">Ristorante</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="courmayeur.html">Courmayeur</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div id="banner">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/banner3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="images/banner4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlayer">
        <h2>Ristorante</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#banner{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:-4px;
}
#banner:not(.home):hover{cursor:url("img/zoom.cur"), auto;}
    .parallax {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    perspective: 1px;
    width: 100%;

}
.parallax__layer--base {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
.parallax__layer--content {
    position: relative;
}
.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

JQuery code

```
function zoom_banner(){
    $( "#banner" ).click(function() {
        $("#testa_pag, #overlayer").toggleClass('open');
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you try to isolate the code in question and post it here? Otherwise, this question will be useless to future viewers once the problem is solved.

Comment: Ok i've inserted the code, i've noticed that the problem is relative to the parallax css rules, but why on other browsers and old version of FF it work?

Comment: i've noticed that's relative to the 'transform-style:preserve-3d;' rule, if i remove that it work but the parallax effect does not.